# Does keras model.predict() returns the same values if run on a dataset or on each dataset sample?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a keras model and when I run:

```
model = create_model()
predicted_values_dataset = model.predict(simple_dataset)
predicted_values_sample_by_sample = np.ones_like(predicted_values_dataset)
count = 0 
for x,y in simple_dataset:
    class_probabilities = model.predict(x)
    predicted_values_sample_by_sample[count,:] = class_probabilities
    count = count + 1
print(np.allclose(predicted_values_dataset, predicted_values_sample_by_sample))
```

I get false, that means that using predict on a dataset gives different results than using it on single samples of the dataset. Am I doing something wrong or is it normal? If it is, why does it happen?

For reproducibility, I attach the following code to be run. Interestingly, sometimes the two prediction arrays are the same (True) but sometime they are not (False)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
import os 
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"

(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(
    'emnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
    download=True
)

def normalize_img(image, label):
  """Normalizes images: `uint8` -> `float32`."""
  return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255., label 

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28,28,1)),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(62, activation='softmax')   
  ])
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
)
testing_dataset = ds_test.map(normalize_img).batch(1).take(1)
predicted_values_dataset = model.predict(testing_dataset, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
predicted_values_sample_by_sample = np.ones_like(predicted_values_dataset)
count = 0 
for x,y in testing_dataset:
    class_probabilities = model.predict(x,batch_size=1) 
    predicted_values_sample_by_sample[count] = class_probabilities
    count = count + 1
print(np.allclose(predicted_values_dataset, predicted_values_sample_by_sample))
```

Comment: SOLVED: it's due to the shuffling of the dataset. Predict works fine, but if you shuffle the dataset you won't get the same sample each time you take a sample from it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `batch_size` is effecting the predictions a little bit. Here is the example, I used some dummy data:

```
X_train = np.random.randn(10000,20)
y_train = np.random.randn(10000,1)
X_test = np.random.randn(500,20)
y_test = np.random.randn(500,1)
```

The model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mse',
              metrics='mae')

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 3)
```

Predictions, using `batch_size = 1`:

```
predicted_values_dataset = model.predict(X_test, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
predicted_values_sample_by_sample = np.ones_like(predicted_values_dataset)

count = 0 
for x in X_test:
    class_probabilities = model.predict(np.array([x])) # model(np.array([x])) is faster in this case
    predicted_values_sample_by_sample[count] = class_probabilities
    count = count + 1
print(np.allclose(predicted_values_dataset, predicted_values_sample_by_sample))
--> True
```

Another example, changed to batch size to its default:

```
predicted_values_dataset = model.predict(X_test, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
predicted_values_sample_by_sample = np.ones_like(predicted_values_dataset)

count = 0 
for x in X_test:
    class_probabilities = model.predict(np.array([x]))
    predicted_values_sample_by_sample[count] = class_probabilities
    count = count + 1
print(np.allclose(predicted_values_dataset, predicted_values_sample_by_sample))
--> False
```

Are they **completely different?** **No**. Take a look:

```
predicted_values_sample_by_sample[-6:-1]

array([[-0.07365198],
       [-0.08797847],
       [ 0.02099334],
       [-0.02701252],
       [-0.00376133]], dtype=float32)
```

With a `batch_size = 32`, predicting all of them:

```
predicted_values_dataset[-6:-1]

array([[-0.07365196],
       [-0.08797852],
       [ 0.02099333],
       [-0.02701252],
       [-0.00376139]], dtype=float32)
```

Edit: For your code, I found out that the indexes do not match with each other:

```
predicted_values_dataset[3]
array([0.02023655, 0.02492297, 0.01587405, 0.00998849, 0.01777572,
       0.0184937 , 0.0110692 , 0.01125433, 0.01712649, 0.01429712,
       0.01935769, 0.02167541, 0.01404375, 0.01612349, 0.02274915,
       0.01137346, 0.01399601, 0.02537212, 0.01364654, 0.01656735,
       0.01827294, 0.01883773, 0.0260612 , 0.01991333, 0.0118144 ,
       0.01157285, 0.01193078, 0.02477211, 0.0140266 , 0.02115744,
       0.01151453, 0.0189477 , 0.01245922, 0.01321447, 0.01219634,
       0.00988797, 0.02337774, 0.01278135, 0.02464633, 0.02499133,
       0.01585869, 0.01721567, 0.01318101, 0.01207395, 0.01401038,
       0.0196951 , 0.0108836 , 0.01665337, 0.01280337, 0.01144315,
       0.01336666, 0.01120847, 0.01587123, 0.01215433, 0.01391562,
       0.01413446, 0.01340299, 0.01450599, 0.01241152, 0.02641938,
       0.01676926, 0.01370175], dtype=float32)
```

and,

```
predicted_values_sample_by_sample[2]
array([0.02023655, 0.02492297, 0.01587405, 0.00998849, 0.01777572,
       0.0184937 , 0.0110692 , 0.01125433, 0.01712649, 0.01429712,
       0.01935769, 0.02167541, 0.01404375, 0.01612349, 0.02274915,
       0.01137346, 0.01399601, 0.02537212, 0.01364654, 0.01656735,
       0.01827294, 0.01883773, 0.0260612 , 0.01991333, 0.0118144 ,
       0.01157285, 0.01193078, 0.02477211, 0.0140266 , 0.02115744,
       0.01151453, 0.0189477 , 0.01245922, 0.01321447, 0.01219634,
       0.00988797, 0.02337774, 0.01278135, 0.02464633, 0.02499133,
       0.01585869, 0.01721567, 0.01318101, 0.01207395, 0.01401038,
       0.0196951 , 0.0108836 , 0.01665337, 0.01280337, 0.01144315,
       0.01336666, 0.01120847, 0.01587123, 0.01215433, 0.01391562,
       0.01413446, 0.01340299, 0.01450599, 0.01241152, 0.02641938,
       0.01676926, 0.01370175], dtype=float32)
```

Something could be wrong with the loop, but that's why it returns false. But they all seem right.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I used batch size 1, but I still get (very) different results. Can it be due to using tf.data.Datasets instead of the numpy arrays you have used?

Comment: Did you inspect the results? It should not be very different at all. It may be because the way you batched the dataset, did you try with `batch(1)`?

Comment: Yes I've used batch size 1 in the dataset, something like: dataset = dataset.batch(1). I always get False as result. Can you provide the model you used to test your code? Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest inspecting few lines of the results that you got. I added the model.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I can confirm that the code you provided works, but still I cannot see why my code does not, since it's quite similair. I Have added it to the question if you have time to have a look at it

Comment: I removed `.take(1)` argument. And edited the answer, possible reason why it returns false. I could not inspect the loop btw.

Comment: Hi! It was due to the shuffling of the dataset. Thanks for your time anyway

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the shuffling of the dataset. Predict works fine, but if you shuffle the dataset you won't get the same sample each time you take a sample from it